# IE8: getting DIVs to float left

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, I am trying to display 4 child div's side by side withing a parent div. I would like the parent div to overflow and scroll horizontally and for the child div's to be next to each other horizontally as well.  Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="b">One</div>
    <div class="b">Two</div>
    <div class="b">Three</div>
    <div class="b">Four</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#a{
    position:relative;
    height:130px;
    width:800px;  
    background:purple;
    overflow:auto;
}
.b{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:400px;  
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #000000; 
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: `ids` should be unique and only used once in the document. `classes` can be used multiple times in the document. I suggest using a `class` for `b` rather than an `id`.

Comment: Good point, I made the changes and still have the same issue. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Use `classes` for repeated elements. `ids` are unique, but `classes` can be used multiple times.
2. Use `inline-block` *instead* of `float`, not in addition.
3. Set `white-space:nowrap` on the container to prevent the children
   from wrapping.

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="b">One</div>
    <div class="b">Two</div>
    <div class="b">Three</div>
    <div class="b">Four</div>
</div>
```

```
#a{
    height:130px;
    width:800px;
    background:purple;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.b{
    height:100px;
    width:400px;  
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Rjn/2/

http://cssdesk.com/exMH4 (for those who cannot see jsfiddle)

Comment: Ahh-ha! Didn't know about the white-space property and will absolutely use classes instead of id's when dealing with repetitive elements. Thanks you for the tips showdev!

Comment: Nice use of white-space and inline-block. Never thought of that for something like this. Is position relative needed? Too bad you can't use jsfiddle with IE8

Comment: @JeremyCook Oh, no? Bummer. Maybe this will work better: http://cssdesk.com/exMH4 I removed the `position:relative` definitions  as they are not needed in this context.

Comment: Looks like cssdesk also doesn't appreciate IE8's subtleties. Hit F11 in IE 9+ and select IE8 Browser Mode to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a floated variant:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="b">One</div>
        <div class="b">Two</div>
        <div class="b">Three</div>
        <div class="b">Four</div>
    </div>
```

```
.a{
    height: 130px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: purple;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 1608px;  
}
.b{
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;  
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYLFn/3/